# How to house a relay module and barrier strip?

Tags: relay, mount, strip, barrier

[image]I’m working on a project where I need to direct 120 Vac with a barrier strip and relay module. I work in a wet chemistry lab and would like advice on buying a housing to protect myself and the circuit when plugged in. I have attached photos of both the relay module and barrier strip. I would also like to be able to secure my module and strip to the housing. Any advice on that will also be appreciated. I anticipate one wire coming in to the housing to provide power and 2 wires going out from the relay module.

[image]

Comment: Have a look for housings which are "[IP66](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_code)" or better, which usually have rubber seals.  You need to see what glands you can find for cable entry.  My suggestion would be: can you mount it high on a wall?

Comment: If the comment from @jonathanjo does not address your concerns, consider improving your post by adding more details and specific questions.  As it stands, your inquiry seems to be rather open-ended.

Comment: It won't protect against all possible faults, but getting a plug-in GFCI for $30 from the hardware store would be a prudent investment.